# Is the free trade agreement between Europe and the US (TTIP) held in secret?

Tags: united-states, european-union, treaty

I have heard in a lot of places that the treaty is being negotiated in secret.

Is this true? If true, is there an official reason for it?

Comment: All negotiations are conducted in secret. So, yes.

Comment: @Avi because reasons? Sources?

Comment: http://trade.ec.europa.eu/doclib/press/index.cfm?id=1230 "We will make the whole text of the agreement public once negotiations have been concluded – well in advance of its signature and ratification."

Comment: @Joze because you can't negotiate when people are nitpicking details, taking offers you don't intend to make in sincerity seriously, etc. You don't show a fool half a job; the electorate can be pretty foolish. This was true of the Iranian nuclear accord, every Israeli-Palestinian final status negotiation, Oslo, the Trans Pacific Partnership, etc.

Comment: @Avi And who says the negotiators aren't fools? How can the electorate make sure their interests are being defended? Besides those are hypothetical(logical?) reasons but not official reasons...

Comment: Are there *any* major negotiations done with full public scrutiny during the negotiation process itself? Before voting/ratification, sure, but this would be like trying to negotiate a car deal while your whole extended family (who know varying amounts about cars and finance) is looking over your shoulder chiming in.

Comment: @Avi - IIRC, TPP actually had a provision for having the agreement itself be non-public. Don't know if TTIP is the same (doesn't have to be)

Comment: @Geobits The deal on Greece was also public.

Comment: @Joze that's not really related to the question, but electorates get to see the agreement before it's approved, just not before it's finished.

Comment: This question contains only unreferenced claims. "I have heard…" does not seem to be a valid proof either.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that negotiations are going on is not exactly secret. The EU Commission needs a mandate for that and is not very good at keeping a lid on things in general. In this case, it's not even trying to and has put a [lot of propaganda material regarding the TTIP on its website](http://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/in-focus/ttip/).

What some people have been complaining about is the reluctance to publish the actual draft of the agreement in discussion. Negotiators claim that handling that discreetly helps them being more effective, which is understandable. But contrary to what some commenters have implied, it's not necessarily always like that in the EU as I think that some drafts have been published during negotiations before.

In fact, even then, the drafts are actually not entirely secret, there have been many leaks, illustrating the point I made in the first paragraph. But the fact that the EU Commission only allows open discussion reluctantly and under pressure from whistleblowers doesn't sit well with part of the public and with the European Parliament, which has been complaining loudly, in part because it has a more limited role in trade negotiations, [before finally falling (mostly) in line](http://www.euractiv.com/sections/global-europe/european-parliament-backs-ttip-rejects-isds-316142).